# ASP.Net MVc Adds an "nav-item selected" class to a the same route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
    <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Brands" ? "nav-item selected" : "")" id="main-nav-item-128" data-id="128">
<a href="@Url.Action("Brands","Product", new { @id=15})" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#dropdown-menu-128">Pwani Life Care </a></li>

     <li class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Brands" ? "nav-item selected" : "")" id="main-nav-item-128" data-id="128">
<a href="@Url.Action("Brands","Product", new { @id=16})" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#dropdown-menu-128"> Pwani Life Care </a> </li>
```

I have those links under lists in my asp.net mvc application redirection to lets say /brands?id=12 and another one to /brands?id=17. However, i want to add the class *nav-item selected* to the links when they are active. any help?

Comment: you mean each link links to the same action but different id ? 
or each link links to a different action ?

Comment: same action with different id

Comment: you can hard code it  then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since I understand that each link directs to the same action but different id, so you shouldn't be looking for action, instead you should compare to the id,
in your controller you can pass the id as ViewBag.TheID, 
then in your html  you can do this

```
  <li class="@(ViewBag.TheID == 15 ? "nav-item selected" : "")" id="main-nav-item-128" data-id="128">
 <a href="@Url.Action("Brands","Product", new { @id=15})" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#dropdown-menu-128">Pwani Life Care </a></li>
```

and so one for each link.